# Get all comments where a user is tagged on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to retrieve all comments where someone is tagged. I looked on Graph API and seems it can only retrieve Post instead of comments, is there a way to archive it? Thanks.

Comment: There is no API for that

Comment: Sad to hear that, instead of using API is there a way to do so? I can only check the comments with tag at the notification center. Once the notification is expired i had no idea how to find it again:\

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API